# why aggregate functions dont let any rows behind from table

Tags: mysql, select, output, aggregate-functions

Hy so my question is, that why do aggregate functions dont let anything behind from the table, they have been running on. So I know that an aggregate function returns a single value, that`s clear, but it doesnt explain me, why the rest of the data disappeared from the output.

```
select last_name, count(*) from actors;
```

This is a code snippet which will obviously not work and I am curious about why is the column last_name not anymore there after the aggregate function has run.

thanks for the answers

Comment: You need `group by last_name`.

Comment: The column should be there. It will pick a name from a random row of the table.

Comment: "MySQL, please tell me the (the as in singular one) number of entries in the phonebook and the (the as in singular one) last name." Depending on your configuration, MySQL either responds with "Omg, which name do you mean? I quit!", or "Ok, I do that, and will choose any random name I find and assume it's the one you are looking for". For more details and/or more examples of situations similar to yours, you can basically read any question (or manual) that contains ["only_full_group_by"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=only_full_group_by+-disable) in it.

Comment: Thank Grordon for your answer... Yes so this is the point, if I use 'group by last_name', then last_name will be the name of the new column (with one single row) assigned to the newly created group but not the name of the original column. The original column is not accessible anymore, for example I can not pick any other columns from the table called 'actors'; this is what I dont understand. The original table is unaccessible right after group by or any aggregate function.

Comment: thank for all the answers guys